# Update local branch without git pull

Tags: git

Let's say I just pulled or fetched from remote repository.

Now I want to switch to a different local branch.

I can do it with `git checkout <branch_name>` or `git switch <branch_name>` but this doesn't update the branch if it's behind `origin`.

Git will helpfully tell you to use `git pull` after switching branches, but this seems to go to the server - which is redundant because I already did a `git fetch` just now to get all changes from the server.

So my question is - is there a way to update the local branch so it's up to date with the remote after `git checkout` / `git switch`, without using `git pull`?

FWIW, it's more logical in Mercurial, `hg pull` fetches all remote changes, and `hg update` updates local from remote, without going to the server again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to update a local branch without doing an explicit `git pull`, you may try the following:

```
# from master
git fetch origin
git checkout feature
git merge origin/feature
```

The above first does a `git fetch` which updates your local tracking branch `origin/feature`.  It then does a merge with that tracking branch from your local `feature` branch.  This is basically the second step of a `git pull`, which is a fetch, followed by a merge with the tracking branch.

Comment: Don't hard-code `origin/feature` in the `git merge` command. A `git merge` without arguments automatically merges with the remote tracking branch for your local branch as noted by @kim in one of the other answers. The remote tracking branch may not always be in `origin` but may be in a different remote that has been configured locally.

Answer (score 2):

git pull is equivalent to:

- `git fetch`
- `git merge @{u}`

Simply change to the branch and use `git merge @{u}` or `git merge remote\remote-branch-name` (`@{u}` is simply a shorthand for the branch upstream)

Personally I prefer to just delete local branches I'm not using. Then it will just create the branch at the correct place every time :-)

<s>edit: I guess you could use the `@{u}` syntax to create a `git update` command if you wanted it :P (see [git aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases))</s>

edit2: `git merge` without arguments merges a branch with it's upstream. Same as if you use `git merge @{u}`.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I just pulled or fetched from remote repository.
> Now I want to switch to a different local branch.

Suppose the branch you intend to switch to is `mybranch`.

Then if you fetch by saying

```
git fetch origin mybranch:mybranch
```

then there is no step two; when you switch to `mybranch` it will *already* be up to date with the server.

Answer (score 1):

Git's equivalent of `hg pull` is `git fetch`.

`git pull` is a convenience command for "`git fetch` followed by whatever I have set up as the usual thing to do after a fetch for my current checkout". To do what you want with other branches without re-fetching, just do what you want with the other branches without re-fetching:

```
 git pull
 git checkout otherbranch
 git merge
```

will do whatever you usually do with your current checkout after fetching, then switch to `otherbranch` and do a merge directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Git will helpfully tell you to use git pull after switching branches, but this seems to go to the server - which is redundant because I already did a git fetch just now to get all changes from the server.

If you have already downloaded from the remote and the remote is named `origin` then do any *one* of these after `git checkout mybranch`:

```
git merge origin/mybranch
git merge --ff-only origin/mybranch
git rebase origin/mybranch
```

You might also want to track this branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin
```